# Case and IF clause in sql server

Tags: sql-server, if-statement, sql-server-2017, case-statement

I need to concate `0` when month and day is less than 10 (`Or Single Digit value`).
When i am using `IF` statement it works, but in `CASE` statement it's doing an addition.

***IF Statement***

```
IF Month(getdate()) < 10
 Begin 
 select '0' + cast(Month(getdate()) as varchar(10))
 END
Else
BEGIN
  select month(getdate())
END
```

***CASE Statement***

```
SELECT 
CASE
    WHEN(
        CAST(Month(getdate()) as varchar(10)) < 10
    ) THEN '0' + cast(Month(getdate()) as varchar(10))
    ELSE (Month(getdate()))
END
```

Comment: Use `FORMAT` instead of trying to concatenate

Answer (score 2):

The difference is that on the `CASE` you are comparing the `VARCHAR` result (by the cast) of the `MONTH` function while in the IF you are comparing it as an `INT`.

Just remove the cast to varchar on the comparison:

```
SELECT 
    CASE WHEN Month(getdate()) < 10 THEN '0' + cast(Month(getdate()) as varchar(10))
    ELSE Month(getdate())
END
```

Can be simplified as the following though:

```
SELECT RIGHT('0' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(2), MONTH(GETDATE())), 2)
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't need such string manipulations. The [FORMAT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/format-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) command introduced in SQL Server 2012 allows you to write :

```
select format (getdate(),'MM')
```

The format string is similar to .NET Format strings. Eg, if you wanted to format a number using a leading zero or optional you could use 0 or # :

```
select format(5,'##'),format(5,'00')
```

This returns `5, 05`.

You can also use the standard format specifiers, eg :

```
select format(getdate(),'s'), format(getdate(),'u')
```

Return `2019-01-11T10:28:41, 2019-01-11 10:28:41Z`

You tagged the question `SQL Server 2017` which means you can use `FORMAT` without issues.

Answer (score 0):

Hope that it helps.

```
DECLARE @MONTH AS NVARCHAR(2)

SET @MONTH = CONVERT(NVARCHAR(2), MONTH(GETDATE()))

IF(LEN(@MONTH) = 1)
    BEGIN
        SELECT '0' + @MONTH
    END

SELECT 
    CASE WHEN(LEN(@MONTH) = 1) THEN '0' + @MONTH
    ELSE
        @MONTH
    END
```

Good luck.